# How to spy on named function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to spy on a named function, exported from the same file from the function I am trying to test. I want to test that function has been called. I want to avoid mocking it completely so that I can have another test for it.

I have utils file like so where I declare my 2 methods

```
// utils.js
export const myFunction = () => {
  return myOtherFunction()
};

export const myOtherFunction = () => {
  return true
}
```

I am then testing them here like so:

```
//utils.test.js
import * as utils from "./utils"

describe("myFunction", () => {
  it("should call myOtherFunction", () => {
    jest.spyOn(utils, "myOtherFunction").mockReturnValue(true)
    const result = utils.myFunction()
    expect(utils.myOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(result).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

It fails because of the following:

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: You cannot spy or mock a function that is declared in the same module it's used, unless it's a method. Either split them or treat them as a single unit.

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense